# Slick grid header row gets messed up

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I have a filter on slick grid header. When I hide a column using setColumns function, the header row gets messed up. Filters overlap each other. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out solution myself.

Function setColumns is re-initializing the display and additional header row is being added on top. So existing header row has to be removed before setting up columns.

I wrote following line before calling setColumns:

```
$('.slick-headerrow-column').remove();
```